# Why is returning 'this' in a JavaScript prototype causing a loop

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

So I have this super simple JS Object I was messing around with and I came across something I can't figure out. When I run this, obj.toString is called over and over until I receive a 'Maximum call stack size error'.  However, if I replace 'this' in the obj.type return to 'this.name', everything works fine.  I realize I wouldn't normally return just 'this', but why is it getting caught in a loop when I do?

```
var Dog = function(name){
  this.name = name;
}
Dog.prototype.type = function(){
  return this;
}
Dog.prototype.toString = function(){
  //console.log(this.type())

  return "Dog's name: " + this.type();
}

var spot = new Dog('spot');
console.log(spot.toString());
```

Comment: Because `"Dog's name: " + this.type()` ends up calling `this.type().toString()` (i.e. `this.toString()`) under the hood, and that call to `toString()` recursively calls `this.type()`.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now.  Normally, calling just 'this' would envoke the built in 'toString()' method and return something like [object Object].  But since i have defined it, it calls my method.  Thanks, that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you stringify an object in javascript, the toString() function is called.

In this case, you have a custom toString() function. Cool.

So let's trace this:

1. `console.log(spot.toString())`
2. `return "Dog's name: " + this.type();`
3. `return this;`
4. `// Hmmmm. How do we add "this" to our string. Easy we call toString().`
5. `return "Dog's name: " + this.type();`
6. `return this;`
7. `// Hmmmm. How do we add "this" to our string. Easy we call toString().`
8. `return "Dog's name: " + this.type();`
9. `return this;`

Uh oh....

Comment: Thanks!  Between you and Frédéric Hamidi, I see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your return statement in the `toString` method should be `return "Dog's name: " + this.name;`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var Dog = function(name){
  this.name = name;
}
Dog.prototype.type = function(){
  return this;
}
Dog.prototype.getName = function(){
  //console.log(this.type())

  return "Dog's name: " + this.type(); // <- Calls toString method
}
Dog.prototype.toString = function(){
    return this.name;
};

var spot = new Dog('spot');
console.log(spot.getName());
```